# animating background colors using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-color, mouseenter

Hello guys so what I am trying to do is to animate a buttons background color using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').mouseenter(function(){
        $('button').animate({
            background-color:"blue"},1000);
    });
    $('button').mouseleave(function() {
        $('button').animate({
            background-color:"white"},1000);
    });
});
```

What did I do wrong? And one more thing, can you explain like for dummies? :D

P.S. : I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery can't natively animate colours. You need to use a plugin, like this one: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/.

Better than that you can use CSS transitions, assuming you don't need to support IE9 or lower.

```css
button {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  /* for prettyness only */
  border: 0;
  color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
button a {
  color: white;
  transition: color 1s;
  -moz-transition: color 1s;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s;
}
button:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button><a href="#">Foo bar</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Nice! It worked! I have one more thing to ask you. How can I animate the text color too? I have an <a> nested in a <button> I tried to do the exact same thing for a (a:hover too) but the text won't animate... I used transition: color 0.5s; and a:hover{ color:black; } Initially it was green.

Comment: The same technique will work for that too; I updated my example for you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not naively support this. Try using the jQuery.color plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
```